# Unable to add silence to end of mp3 using cat

Tags: macos, mp3, cat, lame

I have a mp3 file with silence, s.mp3, which I'm trying to add to the end of an mp3 using:

```
cat file1.mp3 s.mp3 > file1.mp3
```

This worked fine for some mp3 files I downloaded from the net but not the files I created myself using lame.

I'm on mac os x.

Since I'm making the mp3 files myself with lame maybe I can do something that will allow then to work with cat.

How might I establish the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Most file formats are too complicated for concatenation to work. If you know how to program, look at a class called AVAsset in the Mac OS X SDK documentation. If you do not want to program, you can probably find an App that concatenates audio files together.

(Although, to my surprise I do see a "MacHint" that claims that you can cat mp3s together).

Also, see https://superuser.com/questions/78912/free-mp3-merge-for-mac-os-x